# Slice an array of arrays by the first 3 unique values of one of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var items = [[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]];
```

Put another way, I want to loop through the elements of items[0] and items[1] and collect all the elements until I've found three unique values for items[0].

The output I want is:

```
output = [[1,1,2,2,3,3],[0,0,0,1,0,1]];
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: And what happens to `items[1]` ? It just have 2 distinct elements .. I think you just truncated it to the same length of `items[0]`.

Comment: Yes. I want to truncate items[1]. Basically I have a x and y data for plotting and I want to only plot the pairs for the first 3 unique values of x.

Comment: Will `items` ever contain more than two arrays? If it does do you want to do the same thing to the rest of them or do you always want to just process the first two items?

Comment: It will never have more than 3 arrays (x, y, and z). I only care about the unique values of x

Comment: Did you try looping and conditionals?

Comment: @Anton I put my answer, but not if be correct but gives the result, maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, you could give another example?

Comment: Why have separate arrays for x and y? wouldnt this make more sense `[[1,0], [1,0], [2,0], [2,1], [3,0]....]` ? With that structure, this wouldn't be an issue. It would also make it easier to compare both the `x` and `y` coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then the following will do what you want.

```
function threeDistincts(items) {
    var distincts = 0, inArr = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
        inArr = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (items[0][j] === items[0][i]) {
                inArr = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!inArr) distincts++;
        if (distincts === 4) break;
    }
    items[0].length = items[1].length = i;
}
```

Call it like:

```
var items = [[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]];

threeDistincts(items);

// items = [[1,1,2,2,3,3],[0,0,0,1,0,1]];
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jh0L60sw/).

Another version of this function, using `indexOf` (as DTing suggested), will limit the inner loop (in the original function) to the distinct elements only, but considering the high [complexity of `Array.indexOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19287172/2300466) and `Array.push` implementation, better performance is not guaranteed.

```
function threeDistincts(items) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items[0].length; i++) {
        if (arr.indexOf(items[0][i]) === -1) arr.push(items[0][i]);
        if (arr.length === 4) break;
    }
    items[0].length = items[1].length = i;
}
```

Comment: This is basically using `indexOf` but coded with a for loop. O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: @DTing note that I'm not searching the whole array, I'm just searching up to a certain index (`for (...; j < i; ...)`), if you want to use `indexOf` you will have to create a sub-array, which will _possibly_ add greater overhead.

Comment: In the worst case, even optimizing the for loop condition for elements less than i, you get n^2 time. For example `1,2,..<repeating 2's>...,2,3,...<repeating 3's>...,3,4` The nested for loop will have to look through all the 2's before finding the 3's .

Answer (score 1):

Using the newer [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) JavaScript features, which can be polyfilled via [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/) for older browsers.

```
// limitTo3DistinctFromFirst :: [[a], [b]] -> [[a], [b]]
function limitTo3DistinctFromFirst(items) {
    var uniques       = new Set(),
        indexOfFourth = items[0].findIndex(fourthUnique);

    return items.map(sliceToFourth);

    // fourthUnique :: a -> Boolean
    function fourthUnique(el) {
        if (uniques.has(el)) return false;
        uniques.add(el);
        return uniques.size === 4;
    }

    // sliceToFourth :: [a] -> [a]
    function sliceToFourth(a) {
        return a.slice(0, indexOfFourth);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's purdy. Unsupported, but purdy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to track how many unique items you have seen if your objects are hashable:

If you want to stop after you add a third unique value:

```js
var items = [[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]];

function solve(items) {
  var obj = Object.create(null);
  var seen = 0;
  var i = -1;
  while (++i < items[0].length && seen < 3) {
    var element = items[0][i];
    if (element in obj) continue;
    obj[element] = true;
    seen++;
  }
  return [items[0].slice(0,i), items[1].slice(0,i)];
};

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(solve(items));
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

If you want to break out of the loop when the 4th unique value is seen, you can do it like this:

```js
var items = [[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]];

function solve(items) {
  var obj = Object.create(null);
  var seen = 0;
  var i = -1;
  while (++i < items[0].length && seen < 4) {
    var element = items[0][i];
    if (element in obj) continue;
    obj[element] = true;
    seen++;
  }
  return [items[0].slice(0,i-1), items[1].slice(0,i-1)];
};

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(solve(items));
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object as a set to keep track of the number of unique values already selected. This has the benefit of preventing unnecessary iterations.

```
var func = function (data) {
  var selectedValues = {};
  var sliceIndex = 0;

  while (Object.keys(selectedValues).length < 3 && sliceIndex < data[0].length) {
    selectedValues[data[0][sliceIndex]] = true;
    sliceIndex++;
  }

  return data.map(function (axis) {
    return axis.slice(0, sliceIndex);
  });
};

console.log(func([[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]]));
```