# Javascript ES6 computational/time complexity of collections

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, ecmascript-6

What time complexity (in big-O notation) is provided by the ES6 specification for the Keyed Collections (Set, Map, WeakSet, and WeakMap)?

My expectation, and I expect that of most developers, is that the specifications and implementations would use [widely accepted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) performant algorithms, in which case `Set.prototype.has`, `add` and `delete` to all be O(1) in the average case. The same for the `Map` and `Weak–` equivalents.

It is not entirely apparent to me whether the time complexity of the implementations was mandated e.g. in [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification - 6th Edition — 23.2 Set Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-set-objects).

Unless I misunderstand it (and it's certainly very possible I do), it looks the ECMA spec mandates that the implementations (e.g. [`Set.prototype.has`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-set.prototype.has)) are to use a linear time (*O(n)*) algorithm. It would strike me as exceedingly surprising that more performant algorithms would not be mandated or even permitted by the spec, and I would be very interested in an explanation for why this is the case.

Comment: All *O(1)* algorithms are *O(n)* as well, so letting in spec less performant implementations does not make any harm. Probably the less performant implementations may be of some interest in systems with constrained resources, as most likely they require much less code / space.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak The O(1) performance of the keyed collections is generally achieved with an O(1) hash plus a O(n) collision bucket. The O(n) worst-case is for most practical purposes astronomically rare. The space complexity of these techniques is generally O(n).

Comment: "Set objects must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection. " -- from that very page.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Right from [that very paragraph](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-set-objects) your linked to:

> *Set objects must be implemented using [mechanisms] that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection.*

You will find the same sentence for [Maps](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-map-objects), [WeakMaps](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-weakmap-objects) and [WeakSets](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-weakset-objects).

> It looks the ECMA spec mandates that the implementations (e.g. Set.prototype.has) are to use a linear time (`O(n)`) algorithm.

No:

> *The data structures used in this `Set` objects specification is only intended to describe the required observable semantics of Set objects. It is not intended to be a viable implementation model.*

The observable semantics are mostly related to the predictable iteration order (which still can be [implemented efficient and fast](https://wiki.mozilla.org/User:Jorend/Deterministic_hash_tables)). It is indeed expected by the specification that an implementation uses a hash table or something similar with constant access, though trees (with logarithmic access complexity) are allowed as well.

Comment: Thanks for picking that out. My eyes must've glazed over by the time I got to that paragraph. :) So algorithms that are either O(log(n)) or O(1), but not otherwise mandated (provided they are under O(n))?

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: Correct.

Comment: WTH? Aren't they O(log(n))?????? Are they really O(n) on average time? Is O(n) just the worst case?

Comment: @canbax Please see the first quote in my answer again. It does not permit linear average time complexity.

Answer (score 58):

For anyone who is curious, I did a very quick benchmark:

I'm running node 18.16.0.

*This has been edited to include data on strings and deletion as users have pointed out there is a performance difference. However, object is still faster in everything I ran.*

```
const benchmarkMap = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkMap');
    var map = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) map.set(i, i);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) var x = map.get(i);
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkMap');
}

const benchmarkObj = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkObj');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) obj[i] = i;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) var x = obj[i];
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkObj');
}

const benchmarkMapStr = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkMapStr');
    var map = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) map.set(i.toString(), i);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) var x = map.get(i.toString());
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkMapStr');
}

const benchmarkObjStr = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkObjStr');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) obj[i.toString()] = i;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) var x = obj[i.toString()];
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkObjStr');
}

const benchmarkMapDel = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkMapDel');
    var map = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) map.set(i, i);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var x = map.get(i);
        map.delete(i);
    }
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkMapDel');
}

const benchmarkObjDel = size => {
    console.time('benchmarkObjDel');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) obj[i] = i;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var x = obj[i];
        delete obj[i];
    }
    console.timeEnd('benchmarkObjDel');
}

var size = 1000000;

benchmarkMap(size);
benchmarkObj(size);
benchmarkMapStr(size);
benchmarkObjStr(size);
benchmarkMapDel(size);
benchmarkObjDel(size);
```

---

This will yield the following results:

```
benchmarkMap: 189.425ms
benchmarkObj: 41.519ms
benchmarkMapStr: 263.951ms
benchmarkObjStr: 102.959ms
benchmarkMapDel: 271.904ms
benchmarkObjDel: 102.373ms
```

Comment: @domdambrogia if you separate out setting from getting I get: Map Set = 124, Map Get = 40, Object Set = 26, Object Get = 1  (these are ratios not ms)

Comment: @AJP I didn't think about, breaking it down with those stats as well. Thanks for your input, that's a good contribution. I'll see if i can add that into my answer when I have a second. Thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting to separate the assignment from the reading to also learn which one of both is faster for reading.

Comment: "*2017 MacBook Pro, 2.5 GHz i7 w/ 16G RAM*" - uh, that's cool and all, but **which javascript engine** did you benchmark?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when adding `delete` operations and operations are intermixed, `Map` performs much better. https://jsfiddle.net/23hrp0eq/

Comment: @Bergi can't MacBooks only use JavaScriptCore - the Safari engine?

Comment: @beqa I think it's iOS where Apple doesn't let you install your own software. On macOS you can install anything you want, including e.g. nodejs with v8 or arbitrary browsers. Or even compile them yourself

Comment: to be fairer why don't you repeat the experiment 10 times and get the average? Also I think the experiment should use `Object.hasOwnProperty` to check the existence of a property

Comment: @canbax I wrote this in 5 minutes 4 years ago. It was a quick proof of concept to benchmark. If you're interested in your own questions you should be able to extend this rather easily to answer them. The whole point of my answer was to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you add `const str = 'justString'` to your code and than `map.set(str + i, i); ... var x = map.get(str + i); ... obj[str + i] = i; ... var x = obj[str + i];` the `Map` is faster.

Comment: @alexdf Interesting point. Are you implying using a string key rather than a numeric key will boast better performance? Did you compare these to your own benchmarks or my previous benchmarks?

Comment: That's not a benchmark per se as you in fact end up using different types of keys for this 2 data structures: numbers for Map and strings for Object.

Comment: @tnsaturday I disagree. I'm setting an integer in both functions (obj key and map key) and map will accept any primitive type according to [their documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set#key).

Comment: @domdambrogia you disagree with what, a JavaScript engine? you cannot set a number as an object key - it can only be either string or symbol. Try using strings, and you will absolutely different results.

Comment: @tnsaturday I disagree with your observation about it not being a benchmark. I'm comparing data 1:1 with an input to the public method API and an output from that method and analyzing the results. That is a benchmark. You're more than welcome to say under the hood it treats strings vs numbers differently, but that doesn't make it not a benchmark. I've edited the answer to show all different types of analysis for OPs question, if you need more data run your own tests and your own answer. Your comments and sarcasm are no longer being constructive.

Answer (score 28):

The question [Is the Set.has() method O(1) and Array.indexOf O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057200/is-the-set-has-method-o1-and-array-indexof-on) is listed as a duplicate of this one, which it isn't exactly (I've voted to re-open). I'll add these benchmarks here anyway, as the benchmarks on the replies to that question fail to show the full range of differences in performance between `Set#has` and `Array#indexOf`.

**The following is all true for Chrome 93:**

You find that for smaller datasets, `Array#indexOf` actually outperforms `Set#has` or `Map#has`; however, for larger datasets, `Set#has` and `Map#has` are multiple orders of magnitude faster. Which is pretty consistent with what you'd expect for O(n) vs O(1) operations.

Interestingly, despite both being O(n), `Array#includes` is way slower than `Array#indexOf` for a small dataset, but performs very similarly for large datasets. Presumably, `Array#indexOf` takes advantage of some optimization that `Array#includes` doesn't.

Meanwhile, `Object#hasOwnProperty` slightly outperforms `Set#has` and `Map#has` in all cases (at least in Chrome 93).

### Benchmarking code

```js
const [small, medium, large] = [1e3, 1e5, 1e7]

const configs = [
    { size: small, iterations: large },
    { size: medium, iterations: medium },
    { size: large, iterations: small },
]

for (const { size, iterations } of configs) {
    const arr = Array.from({ length: size }, (_, i) => String(i))
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(k => [k, true]))
    const set = new Set(arr)
    const map = new Map(Object.entries(obj))

    const valsToTest = Array.from(
        { length: iterations },
        (_, i) => String(Math.floor(Math.random() * size)),
    )

    const title = `dataset size: ${size.toLocaleString()}; iterations: ${iterations.toLocaleString()}`

    console.log(`\n-> ${title}`)

    for (const [target, method] of [
        [arr, 'indexOf'],
        [arr, 'includes'],
        [set, 'has'],
        [map, 'has'],
        [obj, 'hasOwnProperty'],
    ]) {
        const subtitle = `${target.constructor.name}#${method}`

        console.time(subtitle)

        for (const val of valsToTest) {
            target[method](val)
        }

        console.timeEnd(subtitle)
    }
}
```

### My results (Chrome 93)

```txt
-> dataset size: 1,000; iterations: 10,000,000
Array#indexOf: 185.100ms
Array#includes: 11302.700ms
Set#has: 367.400ms
Map#has: 375.000ms
Object#hasOwnProperty: 252.800ms

-> dataset size: 100,000; iterations: 100,000
Array#indexOf: 10794.100ms
Array#includes: 10476.800ms
Set#has: 6.600ms
Map#has: 6.800ms
Object#hasOwnProperty: 1.900ms

-> dataset size: 10,000,000; iterations: 1,000
Array#indexOf: 12798.900ms
Array#includes: 12435.400ms
Set#has: 0.800ms
Map#has: 0.800ms
Object#hasOwnProperty: 0.300ms
```

Comment: The question you linked does ask "*Is Set.has() really O(1)?*", which definitely is a duplicate of the canonical.

Comment: @Bergi It asks for a comparison between `Set#has` and `Array#indexOf`, whereas this question doesn't. If I Google `set.has vs array.indexof time complexity`, that question is the first result. My answer here is a benchmark-based (as opposed to spec-based) answer to that question, with a few other comparisons thrown in for good measure. Regardless of whether the question is considered a duplicate or not, hopefully someone finds this answer useful.

Comment: what about Set#delete ?