# Timeout error . What is the performance issue in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I've recently started going through some of Codility coding tests and so far I'am getting 0% on my code performace almost every time.

This one https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/distinct/ is very simple code of finding number of distinct integers in an array.

My code is syntactically correct and works properly but what can i do to optimize the performance ?

This is my code:

```
function solution(A) {


    var res = []
    var len = A.length
    for(var i=len;i--;){
        if(!res.includes(A[i])){
            res.push(A[i])
            }
        }
        return res.length
}
```

[image: The performance errors i'm getting from codility]

Comment: If you want to find distinct numbers, either use a `Set` or a `Map` strategy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Slai and @le_m for the additional pointers.

**SET:** `O(n)` space complexity and `O(n*log(n))` time complexity from a data structure standpoint. But seems like V8 does it in a different way Set insertion comes down to `O(1)` making the time complexity `O(n)`.

**MAP:** O(N) space complexity but I think the time complexity will be a little lesser compared to others and could be O(N) because each key look up takes O(1)

More on Javascript collection complexities

[Javascript ES6 computational/time complexity of collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections)

[es6 Map and Set complexity, v8 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation)

```js
// USING ES6 SET

// ONE LINER
// console.log((new Set(arr)).length)

// BREAKDOWN
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1];

var setArr = new Set();

arr.forEach(number => setArr.add(number))

console.log([...setArr])

// USING ES6 MAP
let map = new Map();

arr.forEach(number => map.set(number, "PRESENT"))

console.log([...map.keys()])
```

Comment: Oh I see, it's only to get the number of elements. That's a great one liner. Let me add that to the snippet.

Comment: thanks very much @Nandu Kalidindi  , Although i had to return the size but your code is perfect. thx again

Comment: Each insertion of element into a Set takes O(log(N)) so, N element insertion takes O(N*log(N)). Again please confirm it by looking at how Set works by yourself.

Comment: @le_m I was wondering the same but seems like the spec doesn't require the implementation to be O(1) add/remove/has https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections. @NanduKalidindi I guess you haven't seen the `[...new Set(arr)]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121880/1383168

Comment: AFAIK both Set and Map are in O(1) amortized time complexity for insertion - e.g. for V8 see see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611509/es6-map-and-set-complexity-v8-implementation - the spec doesn't require this though.

Comment: @Slai Yeah, I do, I just added that to give a breakdown of the answer, one liners are not that self explanatory. Sorry, I added the NlogN from a usual C data structure point of view. If V8 implements it internally using a Map then it will be O(1). Please add as many findings to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your code is O(n^2)
You have an outer for loop O(n) and you are using includes method which transverse the array O(n) times

you can simply do this

```
function unique(A) {
   let newSet = new Set(A)
    return newSet.size
}
```

time complexity: O(N*log(N)) or O(N)