# JavaScript for loop performance issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop

What is the best way to loop over a collection of data. The problem i am facing is the low performance. See the example code snippets. Following two methods has the performance issue.

```
interface Day {
    date: number;
    disabled: boolean;
}

// sample data
const monthDays: Day[] = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v: unknown, k: number) => ({ date: k + 1, disabled: false }));
const disabledDates: number[] = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => k + 1);

//set disabled dates
// method 1
let counter = 0;
for (let day of monthDays) {
    day.disabled = disabledDates.some(d => d === day.date);
    counter++;
}

console.log(counter) // logs 30

// method 2
counter = 0;
for (let day of monthDays) {
    for (let date of disabledDates) {
        counter++;
        if (day.date === date) {
            day.disabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(counter); // logs 494
```

In the app i am working , i need to iterate on array 3 to 4 times . This results in low performance of the app. Can anyone suggest whats is the best way to loop.

Comment: Please add what you want to achieve.

Comment: Use a set for disabled days. You could also use a map for month days but I'd start with just disabled days and see where that takes you.

Comment: In both cases it's a `O(n*m)` performance. Your first method 1 *only* counts the outer iterations but not the inner ones by `.some()`.

Comment: could you explain what you want to achive i cannot get it clearly

Comment: @brk and ifaruki lopping over the array, cost in performance of app. My question is how to iterate over an array without performance issue.

Comment: @Gyan i was trying to know what you want to do in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking each element again with `.some` you can spread your values into an `Set` and check with `set.has()` if its inside witch is much faster

Your time complexity drops from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)`

```js
// sample data
let monthDays = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (v, k) => ({ date: k + 1, disabled: false }));
const disabledDates = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (v, k) => k + 1);

//set disabled dates
// method 1

let start = performance.now()
for (let day of monthDays) {
    day.disabled = disabledDates.some(d => d === day.date);
}
console.log(performance.now() - start);

//reset
monthDays = Array.from({ length: 10000 }, (v, k) => ({ date: k + 1, disabled: false }));

start = performance.now();
let set = new Set([ ...disabledDates ]);
for (let day of monthDays) {
   if(set.has(day.date)) {
      day.disabled = true;
   }else {
      day.disabled = false;
   }
}

console.log(performance.now() - start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the exact same performance characteristics with both method 1 and method 2, however, your way of measuring them is flawed. With method 2, you count the outer *and* inner iterations made by the code, while with method 1, you only count the outer iterations. However, `.some()` still does an iteration over the data:

```js
// sample data
const monthDays = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => ({ date: k + 1, disabled: false }));
const disabledDates = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => k + 1);

//set disabled dates
// method 1
let counter = 0;
for (let day of monthDays) {
    day.disabled = disabledDates.some(d => {
      counter++;
      return d === day.date
    });
    counter++;
}

console.log(counter) // logs 495
```

[See also on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJwJ7IN4ChkHIAmckAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6FHADOcdANhERXQD2g3nBDMAvrlwB6Gck40ADr2Kk4uBIJDswyGtrAALdBnYVTAbQC6yALzIAglCiYAdDCiCaACmzJeEABzYwoAZgAGZAkAGmQfADcKKhAAaxBBAHcQONSKanpoAEp7AD54-xJyZFTkAGpkAEY4tk4ePgp4bnYUCSKi5i0dPVauXiJ0SHNKWgYoG3snF3dPbz8AiGDQ5EjouMTckrty2obGgek5HpGOMb41Kdl5GghjQSIm3F49LRTIKEWEWYMEEAJ83zUWEEMH0hhMmHYJTwhEhblG7Q+DnR40mEHYbnY3ggPkx5WRKOQv3A0DqdWYFOQUFeVCgIGI9jsWPcVQgLAIfXphCp-1pkmkQ0JvDc3EEQR8wuKyDkAVl7GQABYAJwAViAA)

Since you have two nested iterations, both methods exhibit an `O(n*m)` time complexity, where `n` is the length of `monthDays` and `m` is the length of `disabledDates`. This is basically quadratic complexity for close values of `n` and `m` and actually quadratic for `n = m` (as is the example).

The way to correct that is to eliminate the nested loops and only process the data once. This is easily achievable by first pre-computing a [`Set` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that contains all `disabledDates`, that way you don't have to loop over an array only to check if they exist instead using [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
// sample data
const monthDays = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => ({ date: k + 1, disabled: false }));
const disabledDates = new Set(Array.from({ length: 30 }, (v, k) => k + 1));

for (const day of monthDays) {
  day.disabled = disabledDates.has(day.date);
}

console.log(monthDays);
```

[See also on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJwJ7IN4ChkHIAmckAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6FHADOcdANhERXQD2g3nBDMAvrlwB6Gck40ADr2Kk4uBIJDswyGtrAALdBnYVTAbQC6yALzIAglCiYAdDCiCaACmzJeEABzYwoAZgAGZAkAGmQfADcKKhAAaxBBAHcQONSKanpoAEp7AD54-xJyZFTkAGpkAEY4tk4ePgp4bnYUCSKi5i0dPVauXiJ0SHNkAGUIMAAeAoYococQCEzZ+Z9nVwwPL19-QJCjcKjY+ITckrty2obG-uZpGEEoeKHdNSxBGH0hhMmHYJTwBBIB1G7SI9mIHDGfEmEHYbiMcHYPkhbiqEAGuCkmm07BEEDc3EEQR8BnAwLMAyAA)

The one time conversion to a set has a complexity of `O(m)` and then each time you loop over you only have an `O(n)` iteration.

- If you can create set once only, then repeatedly iterating `monthDays` don't need to include that operation. Thus the complexity of the operation becomes `O(n)`.
- If you need to create a set *every time* before you loop, then the complexity becomes an `O(n+m)` which is still better than quadratic and essentially linear.

As a note here, this assumes that `.has()` is a `O(1)` operation. This is a *reasonable* assumption that probably holds true most of the time. However, technically, [that's not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections) - the specifications define a sub-linear complexity on set operations, so you *might* have `O(log n)` complexity, which means that the iteration over `monthDays` and looking up `disabledDates` will be `O(n * log m)`. Even then, using a set is probably the easiest optimisation path. If performance is still a problem, then perhaps generating an object as a lookup table could be better:

```
//this should be generated
const lookup: Record<number, true> = {
    1: true,
    2: true,
    3: true,
    /*...*/ 
}

/*...*/

//fetch from lookup or set `false` if not in the lookup
const disabled: boolean = lookup[day.date] ?? false;
```