# Why does javascript return Set elements in not in sorted order?

Tags: javascript, set, hashset

I wanted to use a set in javascript and I found in docs we have Set in js.
But when I tried to use it, it doesn't returns the elements **in sorted order**.

```js
let mySet1 = new Set()

mySet1.add(1)           // Set [ 1 ]
mySet1.add(5)           // Set [ 1, 5 ]
mySet1.add(5)           // Set [ 1, 5 ]
mySet1.add(15)
mySet1.add(150)
mySet1.add(23)
mySet1.add(45)

console.log(mySet1)
```

```js
Set(6) {1, 5, 15, 150, 23, …}
[[Entries]]
0: 1
1: 5
2: 15
3: 150
4: 23
5: 45
size: (...)
```

Isn't the set implemented using a Binary Search Tree like structure in javascript as in other languages like C++, Java
What will be the time complexity for insertion, deletion here.
Or are they HashSet??

Comment: as described in the "documentation" - `You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order` ... and that's the Set *specification* - so that's why it's in that order and not the arbitrary order you want it - as to the underlying mechanism and it's time complexity - that's your second question, and I only answer one :p

Comment: So is it just like normal array? But doesn't push duplicate elements?
Will the push complecxity be O(1) and pop time complexity be O(n) here?

Comment: can you push/pop on a Set now? that's new - or made up - an Array can be sorted, so, no a Set is not "just like normal array"

Comment: When people answer your question, you should indicate whether it resolves it, either by marking an answer as accepted (when it is OK), or commenting on it (when it does not yet resolve it for you).

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the set implemented using a Binary Search Tree like structure in javascript as in other languages like C++, Java

No, because that wouldn't make any sense - sets very often have non-numeric values in them, and may even have non-serializable values like functions and class instances. Binary search only works for numbers (or for values that can be serialized and converted into numeric values one-to-one, like strings)

> But when I tried to use it, it doesn't returns the elements in sorted order.

The order in which values are iterated over is their *insertion order*, not their sorted order.

> What will be the time complexity for insertion, deletion here.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31091772). It's required to be at least sublinear. Past that is up to each individual implementation.