# Which search algorithm does Map.prototype.has use internally?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, search, prototype

This method is relatively fast and I was wondering which search algorithm does it implement internally. I had a look in the ECMASCript spec but it wasn't very enlightening:

[Map.prototype.has](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.has)

Comment: The spec does not mandate a specific implementation. Are you looking for the algorithm used in a particular engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a similar question [Javascript ES6 computational/time complexity of collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/javascript-es6-computational-time-complexity-of-collections)

In summary ECMA only specify requirements, so each browser or javascript engine implements his own algorihtm.

I recomend you to see how Hash tables works [Wikipedia Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)