# Code wants a num of connected components, using Set() works but Map() seems to fail to check if a node has been visited. Output is 7, expected is 2

Tags: javascript, traversal, undirected-graph

The problem is seeing how many connected components there are given an undirected graph. This is the example input.

```
connectedComponentsCount({
  0: [8, 1, 5],
  1: [0],
  5: [0, 8],
  8: [0, 5],
  2: [3, 4],
  3: [2, 4],
  4: [3, 2]
}); //Answer should be 2
```

This is what the graph looks like:

```
        5 ---
        |    |
   1 -- 0 -- 8 
    
    4 ---
    |    |
    2 -- 3
```

This is the solution that works

```
const connectedComponentsCount = (graph) => {
  const visited = new Set();
  let count = 0;
  for (let node in graph) {
    if (explore(graph, node, visited) === true) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
};


const explore = (graph, current, visited) => {
  if (visited.has(String(current))) return false;
      
  visited.add(String(current));
  
  for (let neighbor of graph[current]) {
    explore(graph, neighbor, visited);
  }
  
  return true;
};
```

But this is the code I'm trying make it work for which instead of Set(), uses Map(). I have a feeling that the if condition is not working right because it's never hitting false -- as in, it's never able to verify if a node was already visited.

Another question is I'm told that Set has an O(1) lookup and addition. I think another SO page indicated that the time complexity for a Map() is similar, is that true?

```
const connectedComponentsCount = (graph) => {
  const visited = new Map(); 
  let count = 0 
  for (let node in graph) {
    if(traverse(graph, node, visited)) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return count; 
};

const traverse = (graph, currentNode, visited) => {
  if(visited.has(currentNode)) return false; 
  visited.set(currentNode, 'visited')
  for (let neighbor of graph[currentNode]) {   
    traverse(graph, neighbor, visited)
  }
  return true; 
}
```

I also noted that if I were to console.log(visited.get(currentNode)) after the 'return false' line. I ALWAYS get undefined instead of the string 'visited' that I'm storing. But if I console.log(visited.get(currentNode) right after doing visited.set(currentNode, 'visited), it of course returns 'visited.

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong with the recursion or that I'm building up Map() incorrectly.

Comment: _"Another question..."_ - On topic/problem/question per post. That said... _"[javascript collections time complexity](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+collections+time+complexity)"_ -> [Javascript ES6 computational/time complexity of collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091772/)

Comment: I revised my question's title. I tried to be as concise and descriptive as possible. Thanks.

Also thank you for the linked article. I didn't realize Map() and Set() was specifically mentioned in ES6 documentation. I'm new to programming these things just existed.

Comment: btw, why `2` ...?

Comment: It's a undirected graph. I'll edit my post to show what it looks like.

Comment: Okay, I edited the post to show what the graph looks like.

Comment: OHHHHHHH. You pointed me in the right direction. I realized that in objects, keys are stored as strings. So I was always checking with has("1") from the start. So now my code works by doing parseInt(Node) on the main function. I posted my revisement up top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) checks the value **and** the type of the key.

[24.1.3.7 `Map.prototype.has ( key )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/keyed-collections.html#sec-map.prototype.has)

> 4a. If `p.[[Key]]` is not empty and `SameValueZero(p.[[Key]], key)` is `true`, return `true`.

[7.2.11 `SameValueZero ( x, y )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-samevaluezero)

> 1. If `Type(x)` is different from `Type(y)`, return `false`.

In the "neighbor" call of `traverse()` that `neighbor` is a `Number` and not a `string` - but that's what `currentNode` is in the `.set()` call.

One solution would be to cast `neighbor` into a `String` (or cast `currentNode` back into an actual number before adding it)

```js
const traverse = (graph, currentNode, visited) => {
  if(visited.has(currentNode)) return false; 
  visited.set(currentNode, 'visited')
  for (let neighbor of graph[currentNode]) {   
    traverse(graph, neighbor.toString(), visited)
  }
  return true; 
}
```

Working example:

```js
const connectedComponentsCount = (graph) => {
  const visited = new Map(); 
  let count = 0 
  for (let node in graph) {
    if(traverse(graph, node, visited)) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return count; 
};

const traverse = (graph, currentNode, visited) => {
    if(visited.has(currentNode)) return false;
  
  visited.set(currentNode, 'visited')
  
  for (let neighbor of graph[currentNode]) {   
    traverse(graph, neighbor.toString(), visited)
  }
  return true; 
}

const result = connectedComponentsCount({
  0: [8, 1, 5],
  1: [0],
  5: [0, 8],
  8: [0, 5],
  2: [3, 4],
  3: [2, 4],
  4: [3, 2]
}); //Answer should be

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Voted! Than you so much. Another alternative I did was using parseInt in the main function. So I'd call traverse(graph, parseInt(node), visited). 

Though what do you think is better practice?

Also thank you for thoroughly providing me the documentation snippets. This is incredibly informative. It made me better understand what has() is doing.

Comment: What ever works for you. I would make `graph` also a `Map` and skip all those type conversions.

Comment: Ah! You just keep on giving. That would make my code more convenient. Thanks again. Have a wonderful weekend!